# D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain throws with unknown cause

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, directx, directx-11

for the last weeks i've been running in a strange behaviour of Visual Studio and the game I develop.
After creating the application window with WIN32 `CreateWindowExA` I initialize DX3D11 with `D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain` (see line 304 in codefile [here](http://www.file-upload.net/download-9897562/Direct3DDevice.cpp.html)).

In VisualStudio executing this line will always result in a crash with the following text in the debug output:

`First-chance exception at 0x7713C42D in SpaceLegends.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x0032D7A0.
First-chance exception at 0x7713C42D in SpaceLegends.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x0032D90C.
First-chance exception at 0x7713C42D in SpaceLegends.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x0032D940.
First-chance exception at 0x7713C42D in SpaceLegends.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x0032DA58.
First-chance exception at 0x7713C42D in SpaceLegends.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x0032E248.
First-chance exception at 0x77B070B4 (ntdll.dll) in SpaceLegends.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
Critical error detected c0000374
SpaceLegends.exe has triggered a breakpoint.`

But when I run the exe without VS just as a normal user I don't have any problems to start the application. Also there is no log entry reporting any difficulties or errors!

Due to some reasons I don't get the try-catch around the specific code line does not fire in VS debugging, so there is no exception message I could tell.in

I can't imagine what's wrong with this, neither I have any further idea how to solve or even trace this issue.

EDIT 1:
A full stacktrace from the moment where the exception occurs:

```
ntdll.dll!_RtlpBreakPointHeap@4()   Unknown
ntdll.dll!_RtlpCoalesceFreeBlocks@16()  Unknown
ntdll.dll!@RtlpFreeHeap@16()    Unknown
ntdll.dll!_RtlFreeHeap@12() Unknown
ntdll.dll!_RtlDebugFreeHeap@12()    Unknown
ntdll.dll!@RtlpFreeHeap@16()    Unknown
ntdll.dll!_RtlFreeHeap@12() Unknown
ntdll.dll!_LdrpFinalizeAndDeallocateDataTableEntry@4()  Unknown
ntdll.dll!_LdrpUnloadDll@8()    Unknown
ntdll.dll!_LdrUnloadDll@4() Unknown
guard32.dll!003d6f12()  Unknown
[Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, 
no symbols loaded for guard32.dll]
nvumdshim.dll!5dae52c4()    Unknown
nvumdshim.dll!5dad777f()    Unknown
[External Code]
```

Comment: You'll have a lot easier time debugging if you have symbols. Try setting up the MS symbol servers, and make sure that you're able to load symbols for your own binary as well. Instructions for loading MS symbols in Visual Studio are at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b8ttk8zy%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: I have activated the `Microsoft Symbol Servers` entry and added the *.pdb folders from the directx sdk but still no more information about the error.

Comment: Do you now have a better call stack? Instead of seeing hex numbers like 0x7713C42D, you should be seeing function names. If you aren't, you need to figure out why symbols aren't loading correctly.

Comment: Sadly not, please see EDIT 1

Comment: Unfortunately your code isn't showing up in the stacktrace. guard32.dll probably belongs to your antivirus or firewall. nvumdshim is an nVidia dll. The reason you're seeing the crash only under the debugger is because using the debugger activates the checked heap, and something is corrupting memory. I did't see obvious problems with your source code, but it could be there or it could be in one of these DLLs. You could try disabling COMODO (which is what the Internet thinks guard32.dll belongs to), try updating nVidia drivers.

Comment: Thanks to your tip installing the latest grahpics driver the application is now fully debuggable :)

I had nerver thought about the driver because I have updated it just a month ago...
Thank you!